# Learning Graphical Layout Algorithms

Tags: c++, python, layout, graphics, visualization

During my day-to-day work, I tend to come across data that I want to visualize in a custom manner.  For example, automatically creating a call graph similar to a UML sequence diagram, display digraphs, or visualizing data from a database (scatter plots, 3D contours, etc).

For graphs, I tend to use GraphViz.  For UML-like plots and 3D plots, I would like to write my own software to run under Linux.

I typically program in C++ and prototype in Python.

What books have people used to learn these basic graphical algorithms?  I've seen some nice posts on force-directed layout and various block-style layout algorithms based upon the Cutting and Packing problems -- these are great starts, but I would like a more beginners guide and overview before I jump in.

- [Directed Graph Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552854/how-to-use-a-bgl-directed-graph-as-an-undirected-one-for-use-in-layout-algorithm)
- [Force directed layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713701/force-directed-layout-in-c)

Comment: Why not just write in Python?  What does C++ do that Python doesn't?

Comment: True, for scripts that aren't speed limited such as downloading files and parsing them, I exclusively use Python.  For speed-critical code such as processing tons of database records, C++ is normally 6x faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some sources,

- [Graphic Layout and Design (Paperback)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0827313748).
- [Active Layout Engine: Algorithms and Applications in Variable
  Data Printing](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-6R1.pdf)